# Spring OS dependent mapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-applications

I would like to know if there's a way to resolve a mapping that can be use for Windows & Linux. These are the two independent lines of the mvc.xml, but i want it to work "at the same time" deppending of the server OS if that's possible. Thank you for your time.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/photos/*" location="file:///C:/software/photos/"></mvc:resources> 
<!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/photos/*" location="file:/tmp/photos/"></mvc:resources>-->
```

Comment: Please post the actual XML, with <> and /. Indent it all with four spaces so that it formats as code.

Comment: It would be best to move the photos into the web application. Is that feasible in your case? Then you can use `location="classpath:photos"` and place them in `WEB-INF/photos`.

Comment: I think that its a good way to solve it too, i'll ask my team if i can change the location. Thanks for your time, i'm gonna give it a try to all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to inject a property into the location attribute, and then use your build tool to control which property file is used.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/photos/*" location="${baseContentPath}/photos/"></mvc:resources>
```

Then, create a properties file for each target OS (e.g. linux.properties and windows.properties), and set the value of `baseContentPath` in each:

```
baseContentPath=C:/software
```

Next, make your build determine the target platform and include the correct property file. (If you need help with that, I think it should probably be a separate question; we'll need a bunch of details about your project structure and which build tool you're using.)

On the other hand, maybe you're wanting to build a single WAR that will work regardless of the platform on which it's deployed? In that case, things get a bit more complicated, and I'm out of my depth when using XML-based configuration. It's pretty easy if you convert to annotation-based config (and I wholeheartedly encourage all Spring users to drop XML-based config!).